# Getting elevation at lat/long from raster using python?

Tags: python, raster, elevation

I was wondering if anyone has some experience in getting elevation data from a raster **without using ArcGIS**, but rather get the information as a python `list` or `dict`?

I get my XY data as a list of tuples:

`xy34 =[perp_obj[j].CalcPnts(float(i.dist), orientation) for j in range (len(perp_obj))]`

I'd like to loop through the list or pass it to a function or class-method to get the corresponding elevation for the xy-pairs.

I did some research on the topic and the **gdal** API sounds promising. Can anyone advice me how to go about things, pitfalls, sample code?

---

GDAL is not an option as I can't edit the system path variable on the machine I'm working on!

Does anyone know about a different approach?

Comment: unfortunately, you really do need to get GDAL running on your system to do anything with a raster in Python. With "can't edit the system path variable on the machine", are you referring to [these instructions](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/)? I find this installation method very poor, and I don't use it nor recommend it. If you are using Windows, install GDAL/Python [the simple way](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).

Comment: Yes, I was indeed. I'm not at work right now but I'll check out the link you posted. Looks promising! Thanks for coming back to my question!

Comment: I've used the installer by Christoph Gohlke (linked above) on many work computers, and it is really simple. You only need to ensure that you match the version of Python and either 32- or 64-bit Windows. While you are at it, you should also get NumPy from the same place, since that is needed by GDAL, as shown in the answers below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The provided python code extracts the value data of a raster cell based on given x,y coords. It is a slightly alterd version of an example from [this excellent source](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/). It is based on `GDAL` and `numpy` which are not part of the standard python distribution. Thanks to @Mike Toews for pointing out the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) to make installation and use quick and easy.

```
import os, sys, time, gdal
from gdalconst import *


# coordinates to get pixel values for
xValues = [122588.008]
yValues = [484475.146]

# set directory
os.chdir(r'D:\\temp\\AHN2_060')

# register all of the drivers
gdal.AllRegister()
# open the image
ds = gdal.Open('i25gn1_131.img', GA_ReadOnly)

if ds is None:
    print 'Could not open image'
    sys.exit(1)

# get image size
rows = ds.RasterYSize
cols = ds.RasterXSize
bands = ds.RasterCount

# get georeference info
transform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
xOrigin = transform[0]
yOrigin = transform[3]
pixelWidth = transform[1]
pixelHeight = transform[5]

# loop through the coordinates
for xValue,yValue in zip(xValues,yValues):
    # get x,y
    x = xValue
    y = yValue

    # compute pixel offset
    xOffset = int((x - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
    yOffset = int((y - yOrigin) / pixelHeight)
    # create a string to print out
    s = "%s %s %s %s " % (x, y, xOffset, yOffset)

    # loop through the bands
    for i in xrange(1,bands):
        band = ds.GetRasterBand(i) # 1-based index
        # read data and add the value to the string
        data = band.ReadAsArray(xOffset, yOffset, 1, 1)
        value = data[0,0]
        s = "%s%s " % (s, value) 
    # print out the data string
    print s
    # figure out how long the script took to run
```

Comment: It seems like this is just a less generic, less flexible version of what MerseyViking offered above?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a more programmatic way of using GDAL than @Aragon's answer. I've not tested it, but it is mostly boiler-plate code that has worked for me in the past. It relies on Numpy and GDAL bindings, but that's about it.

```python
import osgeo.gdal as gdal
import osgeo.osr as osr
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

def maFromGDAL(filename):
    dataset = gdal.Open(filename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

    if dataset is None:
        raise Exception()

    # Get the georeferencing metadata.
    # We don't need to know the CRS unless we want to specify coordinates
    # in a different CRS.
    #projection = dataset.GetProjection()
    geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

    # We need to know the geographic bounds and resolution of our dataset.
    if geotransform is None:
        dataset = None
        raise Exception()

    # Get the first band.
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    # We need to nodata value for our MaskedArray later.
    nodata = band.GetNoDataValue()
    # Load the entire dataset into one numpy array.
    image = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, band.XSize, band.YSize)
    # Close the dataset.
    dataset = None

    # Create a numpy MaskedArray from our regular numpy array.
    # If we want to be really clever, we could subclass MaskedArray to hold
    # our georeference metadata as well.
    # see here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html
    # For details.
    masked_image = ma.masked_values(image, nodata, copy=False)
    masked_image.fill_value = nodata

    return masked_image, geotransform

def pixelToMap(gt, pos):
    return (gt[0] + pos[0] * gt[1] + pos[1] * gt[2],
            gt[3] + pos[0] * gt[4] + pos[1] * gt[5])

# Reverses the operation of pixelToMap(), according to:
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file because GDAL's Affine GeoTransform
# uses the same values in the same order as an ESRI world file.
# See: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html
def mapToPixel(gt, pos):
    s = gt[0] * gt[4] - gt[3] * gt[1]
    x = (gt[4] * pos[0] - gt[1] * pos[1] + gt[1] * gt[5] - gt[4] * gt[2]) / s
    y = (-gt[3] * pos[0] + gt[0] * pos[1] + gt[3] * gt[2] - gt[0] * gt[5]) / s
    return (x, y)

def valueAtMapPos(image, gt, pos):
    pp = mapToPixel(gt, pos)
    x = int(pp[0])
    y = int(pp[1])

    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= image.shape[1] or y >= image.shape[0]:
        raise Exception()

    # Note how we reference the y column first. This is the way numpy arrays
    # work by default. But GDAL assumes x first.
    return image[y, x]

try:
    image, geotransform = maFromGDAL('myimage.tif')
    val = valueAtMapPos(image, geotransform, (434323.0, 2984745.0))
    print val
except:
    print('Something went wrong.')
```

Comment: see the edit to my question...thanks for posting anyway! I upvoted it.

Comment: Ah damn! Well at least it's here for posterity. TBH, the maths in `mapToPixel()` and `pixelToMap()` are the important bit, as long as you can create a numpy array (or a regular Python one, but they're generally not as efficient for this sort of thing), and get the array's geographical bounding box.

Comment: +1 for the comment (and code) about reversing the parameters to the numpy array.  I was searching everywhere for a bug in my code, and this swap fixed it!

Comment: I think your `mapToPixel` function is wrong. You need to solve a system of linear equations since you have two equations and two unknowns. Just doing a simple bit of algebra shows that solving for P and L is more complicated than you claim in that function. I think you can fix the function like by using np.linalg.solve(a,b)

Comment: Mapping pixels to coordinates is a 2D affine transformation, that is it can be reversed by inverting the matrix (assuming the matrix's determinant is >0). Admittedly if the source data isn't rectified to start with then you will have to do clever stuff to unwarp the data if it has come from aerial photography for instance, but that's a processing step that happens before we get to this stage.

Comment: When I was using your old function, I was getting division by zero. My change to that function fixed it.

Comment: Then I suggest your matrix (`gt` in the example) is wrong. An affine matrix as used in CGAL (see: http://gdal.org/gdal_datamodel.html) is generally invertible (otherwise you have some funky scaling values going on). So where we have `g = p.A` we can also do `p = g.A^-1` Numpy.linalg is a bit heavyweight for our purposes - we can reduce everything to two simple equations.

Comment: I have re-edited the code to use simple algebra rather than numpy linalg. If the maths is wrong, fix the Wikipedia page.

Comment: It looks like your s is (top-left x) * (y rotation) - (top-left y) * (x scale), whereas Wikipedia has (x scale * -y scale) - (x rotation * y rotation). Am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 4):

Check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25537/3071)... and read [here](http://erouault.blogspot.com/2011/12/seamless-access-to-remote-global-multi.html) for some information. The following info was taken from Geotips:

With [gdallocationinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html), we can query the elevation at a point:

```
$ gdallocationinfo gmted/all075.vrt -geoloc 87360 19679
```

The output of the above command has the form:

```
Report:
   Location: (87360P,19679L)
Band 1:
   Value: 1418
```

This means, that the elevation value at the provided geolocation is 1418.

Comment: Just found out I can't use GDAL as I'm not able to edit my system variable on the machine I'm working on. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. this code which is based on GDAL (and Python, no numpy needed): https://github.com/geometalab/retrieve-height-service

Comment: It's unfortunate that the code doesn't seem to be open source licensed.

Comment: Now it has :-).