# How to get elevation with LibGeoTiff?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, elevation, c++, altitude

I'm trying to get an elevation profile from a geotif file ( downloaded from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/). I downloaded the libgeotiff library but i can's see any function that can return an elevation for given pixel/coordinate or any useful documentation/example to how to do that.
Can someone help me out how to get the elevation? i want to do it in c\c++

Comment: Are you interested in extracting the profile using a linear feature or just the elevation at a given pixel?  Do you know the start / end coordinates (GCS or PCS) of the profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if gdal can help you, you can check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29634/3071). beside this there are some python codes in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29632/3071). you can convert it to c++..

> With gdallocationinfo, we can query the elevation at one point :
>
> $ gdallocationinfo gmted/all075.vrt -geoloc 2 49 Report: Location: (87360P,19679L) Band 1: gmted/30N000E_20101117_gmted_bln075.vrt Value:
>   183

i hope it helps you...

Comment: gdallocationinfo was the key:D thanks for pointing me to the right direction ;)