# Python Script for getting elevation difference between two points

Tags: python, dem, elevation

I have several stream segments 1000 Km long. I need to find the elevation difference between two consecutive points of distance 1 Km starting from the upstream to downstream. How can I get the elevation difference from DEM? I have stream segments in raster format and also in vector format. It would be better if I got some idea on Python script.

Comment: getting elevation at a point: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/raster-how-to-get-elevation-at-lat-long-using-python?rq=1

Answer (score 26):

As a geologist, I often use this technique to make geological cross section in pure Python. I presented a complete solution in [Python: Using vector and raster layers in a geological perspective, without GIS software](https://portailsig.org/content/python-utilisation-des-couches-vectorielles-et-matricielles-dans-une-perspective-geologique-.html) (in French)

I present  here  a summary in English:

- to show you how to extract the elevation values ​​of a DEM
- how to treat these values

If you open a DEM with GDAL/OGR Python module:

```
from osgeo import gdal
# raster dem10m
file = 'dem10m.asc'
layer = gdal.Open(file)
gt =layer.GetGeoTransform()
bands = layer.RasterCount
print bands
1
print gt
(263104.72544800001, 10.002079999999999, 0.0, 155223.647811, 0.0, -10.002079999999999)
```

As a result, you have the number of bands and the geotransform parameters. If you want to extract the value of the raster under a xy point:

```
x,y  = (263220.5,155110.6)
# transform to raster point coordinates
rasterx = int((x - gt[0]) / gt[1])
rastery = int((y - gt[3]) / gt[5])
# only one band here
print layer.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(rasterx,rastery, 1, 1)
array([[222]])
```

As it is a DEM, you get the elevation value under the point. With 3 raster bands with the same xy point you get 3 values (R,G,B). So you could make a function that allows to get the values of multiple rasters under a xy point:

```
def Val_raster(x,y,layer,bands,gt):
    col=[]
    px = int((x - gt[0]) / gt[1])
    py =int((y - gt[3]) / gt[5])
    for j in range(bands):
        band = layer.GetRasterBand(j+1)
        data = band.ReadAsArray(px,py, 1, 1)
        col.append(data[0][0])
  return col
```

application

```
# with a DEM (1 band)
px1 = int((x - gt1[0]) / gt1[1])
py1 = int((y - gt1[3]) / gt1[5])
print Val_raster(x,y,layer, band,gt)
[222] # elevation
# with a geological map (3 bands)
px2 = int((x - gt2[0]) / gt2[1])
py2 = int((y - gt2[3]) / gt2[5])
print Val_raster(x,y,couche2, bandes2,gt2)
[253, 215, 118] # RGB color
```

After that, you process the line profile (which may have segments):

```
# creation of an empty ogr linestring to handle all possible segments of a line with  Union (combining the segements)
profilogr = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
# open the profile shapefile
source = ogr.Open('profilline.shp')
cshp = source.GetLayer()
# union the segments of the line
for element in cshp:
   geom =element.GetGeometryRef()
   profilogr = profilogr.Union(geom)
```

To generate equidistant points on the line, you can use the [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2.17) module with interpolate (easier than ogr)

```
from shapely.wkb import loads
# transformation in Shapely geometry
profilshp = loads(profilogr.ExportToWkb())
# creation the equidistant points on the line with a step of 20m
lenght=profilshp.length
x = []
y = []
z = []
# distance of the topographic profile
dista = []
for currentdistance  in range(0,lenght,20):
     # creation of the point on the line
     point = profilshp.interpolate(currentdistance)
     xp,yp=point.x, point.y
     x.append(xp)
     y.append(yp)
     # extraction of the elevation value from the MNT
     z.append(Val_raster(xp,yp,layer, bands,gt)[0]
     dista.append(currentdistance)
```

and the results (with also the RGB values of a geologic map) with the x,y,z, distance values of the lists
In 3D with [matplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.2.1) and [Visvis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/visvis/1.8) (x,y,z values)

[image]

Cross sections (x, elevation from currentdistance (dista list)) with [matplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/1.2.1):
[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for creating a great pythonic solution and for using matplotlib to create great looking figures.

Comment: Isn't this possible with arcpy ?

Comment: I don't know, I do not use ArcPy

Comment: You typed rasterx twice, it should be rasterx,rastery