# Create cross section with polygon intersects in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cross-section

Is it possible to create a cross section that shows the intersected polygons on the relief (in QGIS 2.0.1)? I would like to try this out for a geologic map.

I'm using VoGisProfilTool:
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/VoGisProfilTool/
and a NASA-DEM

Comment: No, because that question is just about cross sections and not about feature intersects.

Comment: What do you mean by 'intersected polygons on the relief'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with the:

- [qProf](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qProf/) plugin of  Mauro Alberti  and Marco Zanieri
- or by Python scripting in the Python console or with processing: [PyQGIS (QGIS 2) geological cross-sections (colorization of a topographic profile with the colors of a geological map and placement of the points of intersection with the boundaries of geological layers)](http://www.portailsig.org/content/pyqgis-qgis-2-les-coupes-geologiques-colorisation-d-un-profil-topographique-elabore-partir-d), in French, but the scripts are universal...
- look at a pure Python solution with [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) in [Python Script for getting elevation difference between two points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/python-script-for-getting-elevation-difference-between-two-points/59322#59322). The PyQGIS script is a simple adaptation of the original script.

In both cases,the scripts use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

#### Example with a geological map and a DEM: line of cross section (in blue):

[image][image]

#### 1) with [qProf](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qProf/)

[image]

- you can use a point layer with the dip and dip direction of the layers

[image]

But you cannot place the intersections between the geological layers and the cross section line and you cannot adapt or change the resulting figure with the parameters of [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) as in the Python script below.

#### 2) with the Python script:

- the profile in 3D

[image]

- cross section (2D) (with the colours extracted from the geological map)

[image]

or

[image]

- Intersections between the profile line and the limits of the geological layers (polygons layer):

[image]

[image]

- with structural values, apparent dip from dip and dip direction

[image]

- And you can even construct the [Down-Plunge profile](https://stevedutch.net/Structge/SL165DownPlunge.htm) of a fold (look at [Big Elk Anticline Animation](http://www.geo.cornell.edu/geology/classes/RWA/EAS_5220/problem_sets/big_elk_anticline_graphics/big_elk_anticline_animation.html)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Going to try it out right now :)