# Along a line create profile/cross-section lines then extract elevation points from them

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem, profile, cross-section

I know that maybe this question has got an answer, but I need to extract elevation data from a line of a defined length (p.e. 300 meters). Also I want the software (QGIS or ArcGIS) to draw this lines with a regular interval (p.e. 50 meters). The last thing I want to do is to extract elevation data (p.e. each 5 meters) within each line. I was told that this could be done automatically; if not I want to know how I can do this.

This is an example:

[image]

Comment: It's generally best if you include your picture in the question rather than posting a link to it elsewhere (I've gone ahead and edited it in for you). You can do so by clicking the picture icon above the box where you type the body of your question. I've also revised your title to better describe what you're trying to do. It's come up a few times here for both softwares, so you may want to search on "profile" or "section" and review the results. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/ has some answers as well as a couple of other linked/related questions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip, I didn't see the icon to place the pic and visualized it. By the way, there are some links that have no information on the link above you gaved me. @Chris W

Comment: Sorry about that - it's one reason we discourage link-only answers. I've gone through and noted broken links or fixed them as possible. I do recall a plugin for QGIS that would generate the section lines ([station lines](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/stationlines/)) but I don't know if it still works or would meet your needs as it appeared from that [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103659/) the lines were limited to 99 units. If it did, it could be combined with the answer @phloem deleted to completely answer your question. If not, maybe the code would at least help.

Comment: @ChrisW, thanks for the answer it's really close to what I'm looking for, the last thing I need to complete the full answer is how to extract elevation points each certain lenght for each of the lines (may I add that doing this in QGIS is a great tip for me, I want to know a lot from QGIS and freesoftwares, thanks for that)

Comment: @phloem might undelete his/her answer and incorporate that plugin suggestion to it, which should fully address your question. A possible method to expand the lines past the 99 limit would be place circles of 300m at every line/section intersection, then extend the sections to intersect the circles.

Comment: Still missing part of the question but half has been solved

Comment: @ChrisW, Iv'e been working lately with this cross sections, and there's a plugin for QGIS called Qprof, it makes possible to extract DEM data and export it to an excel or libre office calc. My question now, if you can help me, is how to extract info from more than one line. It's very close to what I'm looking with this question, but there's some info lacking.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that plugin, though I see two other questions here that mention it and at least [one answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83605/create-cross-section-with-polygon-intersects-in-qgis/83619#83619) would suggest someone is pretty familiar. I would suggest posting a new question with the details of how you're using it so far and what you haven't been able to get it to do.