# Can you create a borehole log with QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, cross-section, borehole, midvatten

I have UTM coordinates and multiple depths of soil horizons. I would like to create a bore hole log (depth vs distance) that i can edit over with. I only have a .doc file with the coordinates and depths for horizons. Each coordinate has 5 different depths associated (5 different soil types). I would like to create a map and cross section of the bore holes - and label them accordingly to their depths.

Is there a way to do this on QGIS?

I tried Midvatten, however it is asking to import spatialite files - i only have text.

I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you are actually after? Do you mean a  3D diagram with the boreholes and depth labels? Otherwise, how can you incorporate a map and a depth-distance cross section together? Regardless, the first step should be to process your word file into a CSV or text, so that you can import it as a point layer in QGIS.

Comment: yes exactly! I have organized as coordinates and depth. imported as point layer. Used interpolation incorporate the z parameter. I produced a .tif file. However i noticed when i had only 3 data sets the interpolate feature failed but with >80 it worked. I would like to create a 3d diagram with boreholes and depth labels - did you have a link or advice i can follow? Thank you very much, any help is greatly appreciated!!!! On QGIS 2.18.9

Comment: As commenting your reply is getting a bit bigger than the comment word limit, I am placing it in the answer section

Answer (score 1):

To import text data into Midvatten you choose Midvatten > Import data to database > Import data using general csv format. You will get a dialog box pops up and it lets you choose the file then coding and then table that you want it to go into. There is a tutorial here https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/Tutorial.

It is fairly demanding on how the data is formatted. You may have to save your .doc as a plain text .txt file first. It expects the data to be organized in a particular way. It took me quite a while to work out exactly what these expectations are. If you search gis.stackexchange for tag midvatten you will see the questions that I posted and the journey I went on to understand how the data should be organised. It took a while to get it right, but it works well when you finally work it out. Good luck with experimenting and post more questions if you cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DEM for your area you can use the terrain profile plugin and play with the vertical exaggeration feature. You can output the result as pdf as well.

Also, have a look at following posts and websites: [drawing cross-section with polygon intersect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83605/create-cross-section-with-polygon-intersects-in-qgis?rq=1), [using PyQGIS](http://www.portailsig.org/content/pyqgis-qgis-2-les-coupes-geologiques-colorisation-d-un-profil-topographique-elabore-partir-d) (have to use google translate if you need English) and [create a borehole log with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285183/can-you-create-a-borehole-log-with-qgis).

Hope this helps.