# How to extract X Y coordinates and RGB from pixels using python in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, coordinates, rgb

I'm trying to white a Python plugin in QGIS (2.2) to get, for each pixel of a raster image, its X Y coordinates, as well as, its RGB (3 bands) values.

At first I opened the raster file using: rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rfileName, rbaseName)

Now I don't know how to get, for example, for pixel (1,1) its coordinates (X,Y) and its RGB color values.

Anybody could help me?

I know that I'll need to implement a DO WHILE, but I don't know the commands to extract this information of each pixel.

Thanks in advance,
Mateus

Comment: (1) What do you consider the coordinates of a pixel? Its center point, the boundary extent or corner points? (2) Have a look at numpy and gdal in python and also at the ValueTool plugin in qgis. This pretty much does what you want and all you need is to write a loop around it. Although I don't really see your goal of acquiring cell coordinates?

Comment: Hi Curlew, Thanks for your support. I solved the issue using GDAL. Best regards!

Answer (score 5):

As a geologist, I make geological cross section using the elevations values from a DEM and the colors from a geological map, look at the pure Python solution with osgeo.gdal in [Python Script for getting elevation difference between two points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/python-script-for-getting-elevation-difference-between-two-points/59322#59322)

But now, since PyQGIS 2.x, it is easier with PyQGIS and the `QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue`function

- example with a DEM (one band):

  ```
  myDEM = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
  print myDEM.bandCount()  
  1   
  print myDEM.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(229774,111171), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)  
  {1: 221.0}
  ```
- example with a classic raster (three bands -> R,G,B values):

  ```
   print myraster.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(229774,111171), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results()
   {1: 180.0, 2: 142.0, 3: 125.0}
  ```

The result is a dictionary (key= band number) and you can create a simple function that returns the values:

```
def val_raster(point,raster):
    return raster.dataProvider().identify(point, QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results().values()

elevation = val_raster(QgsPoint(229774,111171),myDEM)
print elevation
221.0
R,G,B = val_raster(QgsPoint(229774,111171),myraster)
print R,G,B
180.0, 142.0, 125.0
```

I presented a complete solution with PyQGIS in French [PyQGIS (QGIS 2): geological cross-sections (colorization of a topographic profile build from a DEM with the colors of a raster and placement of the intersection points of the geological layers boundaries )](http://www.portailsig.org/content/pyqgis-qgis-2-les-coupes-geologiques-colorisation-d-un-profil-topographique-elabore-partir-d)

[image]

Comment: Hi Gene, Thanks for your support. I solved the issue using GDAL. Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment so I am posting in answer section.

I came from MATLAB background and always like to have map2pix and pix2map function as giving in mapping toolbox. Using above comments and posted pdf link, I wrote both of them. It might help someone.

After this layer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x, y), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue) can be used to get appropriate values

```
def map2Pix(longitude =0,
            latitude =0,
            transform =None):
    """
    converts map coordinates to image pixel [col, row]
    :param longitude:
    :param latitude:
    :param transform:
    :return: xOffset, yOffset
    """
    if transform:
        # compute pixel offset
        xOffset = int((longitude - transform[0]) / transform[1])
        yOffset = int((latitude - transform[3]) / transform[5])
        return xOffset, yOffset

def pix2Map(xOffset =0,
            yOffset =0,
            transform =None):
    """
    converts image pixel [row, col] to map coordinates
    :param xOffset:
    :param yOffset:
    :param transform:
    :return: longitude, latitude
    """
    if transform:
        longitude = transform[0] + transform[1]*xOffset
        latitude = transform[3] + transform[5]*yOffset
        return longitude, latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

The support for accessing raster data via QgsRasterLayer is fairly limited:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2008-September/004790.html

You can access the value of an individual pixel using the identify tool:

```
x, y = -1.535, 54.634
res = layer.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x, y), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
print res.results()
```

You can access the width, height, extent and coordinate system too:

```
width = layer.width()
height = layer.height()
extent = layer.extent()
crs = layer.crs()
```

**However**, you're probably better off accessing the raster directly using GDAL, for which there are many examples. See this PDF as a general introduction to reading raster data with Python/GDAL: http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf

Comment: Dear all. Thank you for the quick support. I'm glad to solve my issue using GDAL. This library have (so far) the tools I need to work in my project. Best regards!!