# Reading colors on map using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to read the RGB values at certain locations on my
map which is a `.tif`-file I brought into QGIS.

Goal: match species presence points on my map to certain RGB values on the `.tif`-file.

```py
from PIL import Image
img = PIL.Image.open(iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers())
col = img.convert("RGB")
val = col.getpixel((0,0)) #tried to read value at center
print (val)
```

And getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You have a raster layer and should use those methods to access the pixesl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I think you are trying to pass a raster as an input to the .open function, which is not an acceptable parameter.

According to the documentation for the [Image module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html), parameters are:

1. `fp` – A filename (string), `pathlib.Path` object or a `file` object. The file object must implement `read()`, `seek()`, and `tell()` methods, and be opened in binary mode.
2. `mode` – The mode. If given, this argument must be `"r"`.

Try putting the .tif filename directly into the line, like this:

```
img = PIL.Image.open("image.tif")
```

Or providing the full path name as a parameter, like this:

```
img = PIL.Image.open(r"C:\temp\image.tif")
```

Perhaps you might also consider using GDAL to accomplish your tasks. There is an answer
[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90712/how-to-extract-x-y-coordinates-and-rgb-from-pixels-using-python-in-qgis) that might help get you started with that.

Comment: I fixed the problem using GDAL. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!