# Extract Elevation of Points from DEM using Python QGIS or GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, pyqgis, grass.script

I am utterly new to GIS, so please bear with me if I am providing incomplete information here.

I have a DEM file (.dt2). What I am looking to do is as follows:

1. take a series of points specified as lat, long
2. calculate their elevations using the DEM data
3. Output these points in as a list of ECEF coords

I need to do this in either GRASS or QGIS (using Python scripting, not the GUI).

I don't need a complete working code. I am only looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: look at [Python Script for getting elevation difference between two points](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/python-script-for-getting-elevation-difference-between-two-points/59322#59322): how to extract the elevation values ​​of a DEM and treat these values in Python

Comment: I was hoping for a much more high level way of doing this. Please post your response as an answer. I'll hold out for a bit longer for an answer that uses QGIS API or GRASS. If nothing of that nature materializes I will accept your answer.

Comment: Perhaps gdallocationinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html executed with Python could be useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do that with PyQGIS, the `def Val_raster(x,y,layer,bands,gt)` of [Python Script for getting elevation difference between two points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59316/python-script-for-getting-elevation-difference-between-two-points/59322#59322) becomes:

```
def Val_raster(point,raster):
  return raster.dataProvider().identify(point,QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue).results().values()

for point in points.getFeatures():
       geompt = point.geometry().asPoint()
       print print Val_raster(geompt,DEM)
[169.21]
[268.65]
[200.43]
```

with a multiband raster (R,G,B values) the results are, for example

```
[203.0, 177.0, 202.0]
[194.0, 181.0, 199.0]
[109.0, 85.0, 101.0]
```

Or you can use GRASS command [v.drape](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.drape.html) :

In the QGIS console (processing):

```
processing.alghelp("grass:v.drape")
```

In GRASS GIS with [grass.script](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library) (GRASS 6.4.x, GRASS 7.x ) or [Pygrass](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Python/pygrass) (GRASS 7.x)

Comment: That QGIS snippet was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would point out, in addition, that the GRASS model, [v.what.rast](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.what.rast.html) takes a point layer and raster layer as input and uploads the raster values to a given attrib column for all points. To run this in the python console (within a GRASS session) you would do something like:

```
import os
import grass.script as grass

input_points = "<your point list>"
input_dem = "<your elevation raster>"
# Prepare names for the GRASS vector and raster
pts, ext = os.path.splitext(input_points)
dem, ext = os.path.splitext(input_dem)

# Set the x,y values and separator as appropriate in the input list of locations
grass.run_command('v.in.ascii', input=input_points, output=pts, x=1,y=2, separator=comma)
grass.run_command('r.in.gdal' input=input_dem, output=dem)
grass.run_command('v.db.addtable', map=pts, columns="elev double precision")
grass.run_command('v.what.rast', map=pts, raster=dem, column='elev')
```